# Clustering high-dimensional data

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

Every sample in my dataset consists of two components: its $x$ component is a $n\times m$ matrix, and its $y$ component is a $p\times q$ matrix (Feature selection and PCA have been done before). Apart of that, $x$ and $y$ components are orthogonal.

Taking $x$ and $y$ as the axes of such "2D" plane, every data fits a coordinate $\left<a_x,a_y\right>$. I wish to do clustering on them. What should I do? Any works on this?